# How to export a class to node module

Tags: node.js

I have a class which is inside `library.js`:

```
function library(){}
library.prototype.open = function(){}
library.prototype.close = function(){}
library.prototype.remove = function(){}
var library = new library();
```

How could I expose this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**Node docs**](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html):

> The module.exports object is created by the Module system. Sometimes
>   this is not acceptable; many want their module to be an instance of
>   some class. **To do this assign the desired export object to
>   module.exports.** Note that assigning the desired object to exports
>   will simply rebind the local exports variable, which is probably not
>   what you want to do.

From this point, you need to change:

```
var library = new library();
```

to

```
module.exports = new library();
```

Answer (score -1):

don't need

```
var library = new library();
```

instead,

```
module.exports = library;
```

Comment: [express source code](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/view.js)